# How to provide parameters using text file in curl?

Tags: curl

I'm trying to pass parameters in text file and read it in curl command.
Like:I added username and password in text file

```
Sample.txt:
username:"admin"
password:"admin"
```

In curl command, I'm reading like this:

```
curl -K Sample.txt -u $username:$password http://localhost:4502/content/dam/my folder
```

But, this command isn't working.

Could please figure out the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-K` doesn't work like that, it works like this:

put

`-u` *username*`:`*password*

in the `sample.txt` file and do

`curl -K Sample.txt "http://localhost:4502/content/dam/my folder"`

Comment: It's working fine. Thanks! But, when I run it using cron job then it doesn't work.

Comment: crontab has tricky quoting rules, perhaps it's the space in the filename.

Comment: yeah, I tried. It's working :)

Comment: But, whatever we providing, it's in plane text. Is their anyway, we can encrypt text file and read it in curl so nobody can read it?

Comment: AFAICT no. best make it so that the password can't do serious damage if it leaks

Comment: Didn't get this point! Could you please explain?

Comment: what you ask is impossible.  if the password could be encrypted in the file curl could be used to send it to a localhost socket, and so it could still be read easily.